# Como obter a senha do MySql para conexão utilizando o getenv()

Tags: php

Utilizo atualmente a forma de conexão padrão para obter os dados do `MySql`, porém sei que para maior segurança é utilizado o `getenv()`, porém não o sei como fazer para que ele recupere a senha de conexão com meu banco de dados.

Segue abaixo como é feita minha conexão com o MySql

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "guaraparivirtual");
?>
```

Comment: O uso de `getenv` e `putenv` não vai tornar nada mais seguro, não sei quem lhe contou, mas isto é muito relativo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Qual é o local e forma de atribuir a senha do meu banco de dados seguramente?

Comment: Não é questão de local, é questão de entender o que é algo *"relativo"*, eu posso chegar e te afirmar que avião é o meio de transporte mais seguro do mundo e ainda sim ocorrer um acidente gravíssimo de avião, existem muitos fatores a se levar em conta, não tem formula mágica pronta e unica de se fazer algo, no momento estou sem tempo algum para explicar a questão segurança, mas logo te digo, entre usar `putenv` e um `array` com os dados da navegação você não terá muita diferença.

Comment: É mais fácil criar um arquivo separado com o usuário, senha e já realizar a conexão ali, e depois utilizar uma ferramenta de criptografia de arquivos php como o [PHP LockIt](http://www.phplockit.com/), depois apenas inclua o arquivo criptografado no include/require nos seus outros arquivos que necessitam de conexão;

Answer (score 3):

**Não tem sentido algum usar `putenv`**, se for para fazer isto é melhor jogar tudo em um `array` ou `object`, algo como:

### config.php

> o `return` é reconhecido no `include`

```
<?php

return (object) array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => 'meupassword',
    'db'   => 'meubanco',
);
```

### pagina.php

```
$config = require 'config.php';

$con = new mysqli($config->host, $config->user, $config->pass, config->banco);
```

### A questão da segurança

Talvez essa historia que tenha ouvido que `getenv` seja mais seguro é se configurar se refira a configurar tais dados fora do `.php`, nas variáveis de ambiente para ser mais exato, eu não vou entrar em mérito de discussão sobre isto, pois não faz muito sentido, as variáveis estarão acessíveis a qualquer aplicação de qualquer forma, de ambas formas, usando um `array/object` ou usando as [*variáveis de ambiente* (Environment Variables)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vari%C3%A1vel_de_ambiente) você pode estar seguro tanto quanto inseguro, se a tua máquina servidor tiver alguma "aplicação maligna" ele pode roubar suas senhas aonde estiverem, não fará diferença, se teu servidor é inseguro então o problema **não é nos teus** phps e sim no teu servidor.

Agora se o teu medo é que alguém consiga acesso aos `.php`, usar `putenv` não vai resolver nada.

Resumindo, se o seu medo é algum usuário via internet acessar a senha de alguma forma usar `getenv` não é solução, é impossível o visitante ter acesso a estes dados a não ser que você tenha exposto eles com `echo`, `print`, `print_r` ou algum depurador muito do mal feito (é altamente recomendado desligar depuradores no **servidor de produção**).

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tens que fazer algo como isto.

```
putenv("host=localhost");
putenv("user=root");
putenv("pass= ");

$db_host=getenv("host");
$db_user=getenv("user");
$db_pass=getenv("pass");
$db_name="tese";

$con = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Para que serviria `getenv('')`? Não seria mais fácil colocar vazio mesmo? `$db_pass = ''`

Comment: Sim ;) mas era se tivesse alguma pass e não tivesse posto aqui

Comment: @BrnPer Perdão pela minha falta de conhecimento. Mas, qual a utilidade em passar as informações no `getenv()` ou declarar diretamente como fiz?

Comment: @Gladison não te preocupes. Todos os dias aprendemos sempre coisas novas. O getenv()  vai procurar variáveis do ambiente. A vantagem de usar     getenv()  é que as variáveis em PHP são case-sensitive, com o getenv() ele irá procurar sem se preocupar com as letras maiúsculas ou minúsculas, visto que vai ser tudo igual para o getenv(). Um exemplo é este: $_SERVER['Path']  é necessário que fique PATH se não o PHP não encontra, com getenv('path') já consegue. Espero que tenhas percebido.

Comment: @BrnPer Então qual é a diferença de utilizar `$senha = '1234'` e `getenv()` no que se refere a segurança? Se eu tenha que de toda froma atribuir a senha ao `getenv()`.

Comment: @Gladison no que se refere à segurança muito pouca. O getenv() e putenv() são usados para passar variaveis do servidor sem estar preocupado de voltar a reescrevê-las ou sabe-las. Como por exemplo usas o putenv() e poes um dado de um input como variavel, noutro segmento do codigo podes usar getenv(" poes o nome" ) e trabalhas com esse dado sem saberes o que está logo ser mais seguro. Espero ter sido claro para ti

Comment: @BrnPer Agora compreendi! Mas o código que me passou acima está dando erro `Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'guaraparivirtual' in C:\xampp\htdocs\guaraparivirtual\conexao.php on line 7` a linha 7 é essa `$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);`

Comment: @Gladison eu tinha um erro no post que esqueci-me, mas já corrigi

Comment: @Gladison já conseguiu resolver o seu problema Gladison?

Comment: @BrnPer Consegui sim! Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Show de bola.

Comment: @Gladison de nada ;) só não se esqueça de avaliar depois a minha resposta como resposta à sua pergunta

Comment: Utilizar `getenv` não absolutamente relação alguma sobre o PHP ser ou não *case-insensitive*. O que acontece é que utilizando variáveis de ambiente, os dados sensíveis não ficam presente no corpo do código. Isso apenas facilita a distribuição do código. Nenhuma segurança é adicionada. Utilizar `getenv` em conjunto com `putenv` talvez não faz sentido. Se alguém conseguir acesso ao servidor e conseguir ler seu código fonte, ele também conseguirá acessar as variáveis de ambiente, ou seja, isso não resolve o problema de segurança, apenas de distribuição do código, como postá-lo no GitHub, exemplo.

Comment: Mas o getenv() tem essa vantagem sobre o $SERVER, visto que o getenv()   não obriga a sensitive

Comment: E aliás se o resultado do putenv estiver associado com uma input, depois de uma vez preenchida, através do código-fonte o utilizador não consegue de maneira nenhuma saber a pass.

Comment: Mas se tem acesso ao código fonte, tem acesso também às variáveis de ambiente. Nada muda em questão de segurança. Utilizar `putenv` associado à um `input` não faz sentido. Ser *case-insensitive* não é vantagem e não entendi qual é a relação do `$SERVER` com a pergunta.

Comment: $SERVER é uma das outras maneira de buscar variáveis de ambiente, certo? E não percebi como é que com acesso ao código fonte é possível ter acesso às variáveis de ambiente?